# A thorough study of type III von Neumann algebras

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

In many refernce books and papers, type III von Neumann algebra factors were well studied.

If  $M$ is a type III von Neumann algebra has non-trivial centers, what is the structure of $M$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given an abelian subalgebra $N$ of a von Neumann algebra $M$, such as the center of $M$, one can always write
$N=L^\infty (X)$, for some measure space $X$.   Furthermore
one can decompose $M$ as a "direct integral"
$$
M=\int_X^\oplus M_x\,dx
$$
(sort of a
continuous direct sum) of von Neumann algebras
indexed by $X$.   When $N$ is the center of $M$ the factors $M_x$ in this
decomposition are simple von Neumann algebras (called "factors" precisely for that reason) [**1**, 14.2.3]. The moral of the story is
that all there remains to be done  about von Neumann algebras is to study factors, so no one cares about non-simple von Neumann algebras
anymore!

[1] *Kadison, Richard V.; Ringrose, John R.*, Fundamentals of the theory of operator algebras. Vol. 2, Pure and Applied Mathematics, 100-2. San Diego, CA: Academic Press, Inc.

Comment: What is the form of $M_x$? Does there exist other reference books to give a complete proof of $M=\int_X^\oplus M_x\,dx$?

Comment: Part of the trouble in understanding the $M_x$ is that they are only defined a.e.  Intuitively speaking, you take a decreasing family of measurable sets $\{E_i\}_i$ of positive measure, whose intersection is $\{x\}$, and look at the limit of subalgebras $1_{E_i}M$.

Comment: Another reference is Takesaki, vol 1, section 8.  Look for Theorem 8.21 (Existence of Disintegration).

Comment: ，Section 8 ? there are five chapters in vol 1.

Comment: Do you still need help locating Theorem 8.21?

Comment: Is it in Vol 2, Chapter VIII, Modular Automorphism groups, Theorem 4.11?

Comment: Sorry, it is Volume 1, Chapter IV, section 8, Theorem 8.21.  In my edition it is on page 275.

Comment: Thnak you so much!

Comment: I have another question: In the theorem, the author mentions that every von nuemann algebra is a direct integral of factors. If $M$ has a normal state  $\tau$. Is $\tau$ also the normal state of its intgral of factor?

Comment: Check Proposition 8.34 in that same section of Takesaki, vol 1.

Comment: I still feel puzzled. $$ M=\int_X^\oplus M_x\,dx $$, is every $\int_X M_x\, dx$ a von Neumann algebra?

Comment: Does Theorem 8.18 answer your question?

Comment: I am quite confused the notation. What is the explicit form of $\int_{\Gamma} M_(r)\, d\mu(r)$?

Comment: It is the set of all decomposable operators $x$ (Definition 8.15) with $x(\gamma)\in M_\gamma$.